# Pyspark predict using kafka direct stream

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to pull kafka data to spark streaming, load an already built model from HDFS and then make predictions using kafka message.

I tried several methods but I'm stuck at model.predict because of a TypeError: Cannot convert type  into Vector

The data received from kafka is float comma separated.

Here is my code :

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaForecast")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)

# Create stream to get kafka messages
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ["my_topic"], {"metadata.broker.list": "kafka_ip"})

features = directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.map(lambda s: Vectors.dense(s[1].split(","))))

model = LinearRegressionModel.load(sc, "hdfs://hadoop_ip/model.model")

#Predict
predicted = model.predict(features)
```

I also tried this :

```
lines = directKafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
features = lines.map(lambda data: Vectors.dense([float(c) for c in data.split(',')]))
```

But this time, features is of type TransformedStream which won't work for preidctions ...

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the issue was to try to read data from kafka even if the topic is empty.

This solved my problem :

```
def predict(rdd):
    count = rdd.count()
    if (count > 0):
        features = rdd.map(lambda s: Vectors.dense(s[1].split(",")))

        return features
    else:
    print("No data received")

directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: predict(rdd))
```